# Debugging Classic ASP causes Visual Studio 2008 to crash - how can I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic, attach-to-process

I'm debugging classic asp code using VS 2008 sp1 on windows 7.  Everything works great, I attach to the process and can debug.  However, If I stop debugging visual studio will crash.

I read the recycling the app pool would help, but it has not helped me end a debugging session with out crashing.  I have hunted through Google and stack overflow for a solution, but so far I've mainly found complaints.

Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: I didn't realize that it was possible to use any debugger on classic ASP.  Whoa.

Comment: @recursive: Just pop a "stop" statement at the point at which you want to debug, when that line of code is hit you'll get a dialog asking you which (installed) debugger you'd like to attach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coworker found answer:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB967631

This QFE fixes three complete separate issues in the VS2008 SP1 Debugger:

- Debugger can hang the IDE after setting a breakpoint when working with a large C++ project
- Breakpoints do not bind correctly when an MSIL file is built containing .line directives
- **VS crashes when debugging a classic ASP web and debugging is stopped.**

Comment: You have just made me sooo happy :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem and the conclusion I came too after scouring the web and reading other user's stories is that VS 2008 has a bug when debugging classic asp! It crashes when you stop debugging. Sort of a time killer to have to restart VS every time you debug.

I have had to resort to using VS2005 to open classic ASP projects and debug them there.  If I need to have the ability to work on an app in both 2005 and 2008 I've found that you can have 2 separate solution files, each created by the applicable app (for example I've got appName.sln  that I open in VS2008 and then appName2005.sln that I open in VS2005).   You will need to create a new solution in VS2005 and add the files, then save that solution with the slightly different .sln filename.  This works, it just takes a bit of time to setup.

Supposedly MS is going to resolve this issue in VS2010 but they didn't consider it an important enough problem to issue a patch for VS2008.